# Which ajax control toolkit version?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

If I'm using Visual Studio 2008 targeted to ASP.NET 2.0, then which version of the Ajax Control Toolkit should I be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the Toolkit version [1.0.20229.20821](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=11121), *AjaxControlToolkit.zip* the dll's are targeted to .NET 2.0 and you need also the  [ASP.NET AJAX Extensions 1.0 for .NET 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=ca9d90fa-e8c9-42e3-aa19-08e2c027f5d6&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 1):

Release 11119 seems to be the latest release of the toolkit that targets .net 2.0. You can find it here:

http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=8513

If you are using Visual Studio 2008 then the AJAX VS 2008 Templates might be handy as well as the ASP.Net Ajax Extensions V1.0 already mentioned. The templates provide a Visual Studio project that automagically sets up the web.config and gives you a template 'default.aspx' with AJAX ready to go.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/downloads/